# Working With Specific XML structure

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to get some data from an XML document. I have no control over the schema. If it were up to me I would have chosen another schema. I am using C#'s XPATH library to get the data.

XML DOC

```
<Journals>
    <name>Title of Journal</name>
    <totalvolume>2</totalvolume>
    <JournalList>
        <Volume no="1">
            <Journal>
                <issue>01</issue>
                <Title>Title 1</Title>
                <date>1997-03-10</date>
                <link>www.somelink.com</link>
            </Journal>
            <Journal>
                <issue>02</issue>
                <Title>Title 3</Title>
                <date>1997-03-17</date>
                <link>www.somelink.com</link>
            </Journal>
        </Volume>
        <Volume no="2">
            <Journal>
                <issue>01</issue>
                <Title>Title 1</Title>
                <date>1999-01-01</date>
                <link>www.somelink.com</link>
            </Journal>
            <Journal>
                <issue>01</issue>
                <Title>Title 2</Title>
                <date>1999-01-08</date>
                <link>www.somelink.com</link>
            </Journal>
        </Volume>
    </JournalList>
 </Journals>
```

I am trying to get all the data in the Volume 2 node. Here is what I tried so far:

**C# Code**:

```
protected void loadXML(string url)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(url);

    string strQuery = "Volume[@no='2']";

    XmlElement nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList JournalList = nodeList.SelectNodes(strQuery);

    foreach (XmlElement Journal in JournalList)
    {
        XmlElement temp = Journal;
    }
}
```

It seems there are no nodes in JournalList. Anyone? Thanks in advance/

Comment: Note that using an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is easier than an XmlDocument. With XmlDocument you are basically limited to using XPath queries, whereas with XDocument you can [use LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16796327/109702).

Comment: @slugster LINQ is nice and all, but it's not inherently *better*. XPath can handle this situation (and many much more complex ones) with ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for "Volume" nodes directly under the "Journals" node

Change this:

```
string strQuery = "Volume[@no='2']";
```

To this, in order to look for "Volume" nodes under the "JournalList" node:

```
string strQuery = "JournalList/Volume[@no='2']";
```

Also, there's a couple typos in your XML:

```
</Volume no="2">  ->  <Volume no="2">   // no open tag found

</Journal>        ->  </Journals>       // expecting end tag </Journals>
```

---

From your comment below:

> how would I go about access each journal? for example. I want irrate through each "journal" and get the title of the journal?

In order to do that, you could modify your code slightly:

```
var nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
var volume = nodeList.SelectSingleNode(strQuery);
foreach (XmlElement journal in volume.SelectNodes("Journal"))
{
    var title = journal.GetElementsByTagName("Title")[0].InnerText;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but i have a questions. how would I go about access each journal? for example. I want irrate through each "journal" and get each journal title within Volume 2?
I want to use a foreach statement, but it seems i am only i am grabbed Volume 2. How would I go about getting the nodes within it?

Comment: @Grant I believe your second code sample contains a mistake. Shouldn't you iterate over `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//JournalList/Volume[@no=2]")` instead of over `volume.SelectNodes("Journal")`?

Comment: Ah, I see. It's implemented a bit more complicated than it needs to be, but it would work. `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//JournalList/Volume[@no = 2]/Journal")` would select the wanted nodes straight-away, saving a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
//...
string path="Path of your xml file"
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var volume2= doc.Descendants("Volume").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("no").Value == "2");
```

Comment: `doc.Descendants("Volume").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("no").Value == "2")` - 77 characters. `doc.SelectNodes("//Volume[@no=2]")` - 34 characters, and easier to read.